# Redirect to other page when mobile

Tags: redirect, mobile

I am looking for a simple clean solution when someone visits my **homepage** with a mobile device. Should I use something like Mobile Detect? I've seen many plugins with lots of downvotes or crashing.

Is it otherwise possible to only add a javascript thingie on the homepage only?

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window)  window.location = 'http://someurl.com/single/page';
```

Comment: Why would you want to redirect the user to another page? He wants to see what he clicked on in search results or wherever...

Comment: Well, when you have parallax scrolling containg sections (actually pages), you want better performance on mobile devices. So the homepage containing all pages redirects to the top page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`wp_is_mobile`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) with [`wp_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() AND is_front_page() ) {
    wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
}
```

You can add the js directly to a front-page.php or home.php file or [`enqueue`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) it directly from either file.

Example:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script');
function load_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/your-script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you to detect

```
var isMobile = {
Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
},
BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
},
iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
},
Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
},
Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
},
any: function() {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
}
```

};

```
if(isMobile.any()) {   alert("This is a Mobile Device");}
```

You can read more about it here.
http://jstricks.com/detect-mobile-devices-javascript-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wordpress, give this plugin a try - http://www.ultimate-wordpress-mobile-redirect.com

With this plugin you can set a unique redirect URL for every page and post of your website.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript Thingie!! 
You should have tried Mobile Detect first. That should suffice your requirement. If you need  more help using the plugin, consider posting on their support forum on WP repo.